# laravel and mongodb - how about migrations

Tags: mongodb, laravel

I'm using Laravel 3 and MongoHQ database.

In some tutorials (example: http://codehappy.daylerees.com/authentication) I need to create Schemas and Migrations, but how to do this with NoSQL database? Or should I keep this step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel (Version 4&3) uses the Eloquent ORM for database work. (including Migrations and Schemas)
Currently Eloquent only supports four database systems: **MySQL, Postgres, SQLite, and SQL Server.**

With MongoHQ you can not create Migrations or Schemas.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/database

Comment: note that Doctrine 2 and Mandango can be used as ORMs in Laravel so that isn't true, Doctrine 2 does support migrations